# Data not getting shown in view

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, ionic2

As a student, I'm currently stuck with trying to create the following:

I have in my sidemenu (based on the sidemenu template) a profilepicture & displayname that I want to swap with data from my firebase database.

I have the following code:

1. App.html

   ```
   <img id="profile-image" src="assets/profile/{{ photoURL }}" alt="{{ displayName }}"/>
   <div id="profile-name" text-center class="width-full">{{ displayName }}</div>
   ```
2. App.component.ts

   ```
   var displayName;
   var photoURL;

   export class MyApp  
   {  

   constructor()  
   {       
        this.setUserData();
   ```

   }

   setUserData()
         {
       this.uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

   ```
   console.log("UID: "+ this.uid);

   let ref = firebase.database().ref('/userProfile').child(this.uid);

   ref.once('value', function(snapshot)
   {
     //CALLBACK
     var key = snapshot.key;
     var em = snapshot.child("/email").val();
     var nm = snapshot.child("/name").val();
     var dpn = snapshot.child("/displayName").val();
     var pURL = snapshot.child("/photoURL").val();

     //LOG
     console.log("KEY: "+key);
     console.log("NAME: "+nm);
     console.log("DISPLAYNAME: "+dpn);
     console.log("EMAIL: "+em);
     console.log("PHOTOURL: "+pURL);

     displayName = dpn;
     photoURL = pURL;

   }, function(error)
   {
     // The callback failed.
     console.error(error);
   });
   ```

In my console I see that the UID is getting loaded, the correct data is getting fetched,
but I cannot seem to get the result on my view? It just stays empty.

Can somebody explain what I'm missing or what I'm supposed to do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the variables inside the class,

```
export class MyApp{
 displayName :string;
 photoURL :string;
```

Comment: If I declare the variables inside the class, and change the properties to this.displayName. I get a runtime error: this is null. (Since the data is loaded asynchronously)

Comment: I'm trying to get it aligned, but for some reason it splits my code.